# How to calculate the number of strings of length n containing substring ACA?

Tags: statistics

If I have an alphabet over letters A,C,T and G, how to calculate the number of strings of length n containing substring ACA ?

I know how to calculate for substrings that can not overlap and it uses inclusion–exclusion principle but I don't know how to generalize it to work for all substrings?

For non overlapping substrings of length m, over an alphabet with c letters  the calculations goes:
\begin{equation}
 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\lfloor  \frac {n} {m} \rfloor} {(-1)^{k-1}  \cdot { {n-k \cdot m+k}\choose{k}}  \cdot c^{n-k*m}} \\
\end{equation}

Comment: Assuming that A,T,G,C equally likely. In DNA, it's close, but not exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a set of coupled recurrences.  Divide the $n$ letter strings into
1) A(n), those that contain ACA
2) B(n), those that do not contain ACA but end in AC
3) C(n), those that do not contain ACA but end in A
4) D(n), all others.

Write a recurrence for each of these in terms of the number of each kind of string of length $n-1$.  You can view the four equations as a matrix multiplying the vector of numbers of strings of length $n-1$ to get the vector of the number of strings of length $n$.  The largest eigenvalue of the matrix is the asymptotic growth rate.  For small $n$ you can just write the recurrence into a spreadsheet and copy down.